# Android app loading screen background image takes too long to load

Tags: android

I am developing an android app. In my case, when the app starts it displays a temporary screen while AsyncTask fetches data in the background. This temporary screen contain only a background image (20 KB). But in this background takes a while to load. As a result of this when I start my app I only see a white screen, after a while it shows the background image. Any ideas on how to get rid of this problem and show the background image from the beginning
Here is the xml file of the start screen

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/start"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: This could depend on several factors. What are you testing it on? The notoriously slow emulator? Are you doing something else before it loads that's taking a long time?

Comment: I am testing on emulator. I am not doing anything else before loading the screen. Only after loading, uses AsyncTask to get date

Comment: I doubt that the image is taking long to load. What happens if you remove the call to `new Refresh().execute();`? You probably need to move that call to `onResume()` or `onStart()`.

Comment: This shouldn't take that long. I use the emulator and load lots of images, some of them up to 2 MB with no lag. There is probably something else going on in your program, i.e. the "white" screen is one activity and the one with the drawable is a different activity. If you are not using a .png, try to convert it to one, if able.

Comment: can you show your code please?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  This awesome person has the [explanation](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/).

TL;DR (only in case the link goes bad, I would go read it though)  :"the purpose of preview windows is to give the user immediate feedback that the app launched, but it also gives your app time to initialize itself. When your app is ready to run, the system removes the window and displays your app’s windows and views."  You can set this in themes.  Minimally, my setup:

Theme in /res/values/styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_bg</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Base theme for any other activity other than your starting one. -->
    <!-- If only one activity, just set the splash bg as its bg -->
    <style name="MyTheme.MainActivity" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_splash_bg</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme.MainActivity"
    ...
    <!-- Set the MainActivity theme, can be skipped if you only have -->
    <!-- one activity and did not setup anything other than your base theme -->
```

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MainActivity.this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.app_bg);
}
```

Basically, you setup a theme with the splash background for your starting activity.  You then set the background to your normal one during `onResume` of said starting activity.

Also, you can just comment out the `windowBackground` declaration in the starting activity theme to see the original (I assume) "ugly white" screen on launch.

Answer (score 0):

In your  temporary screen, first you should do setContentView() and then call AsyncTask (With a progress bar, which is dismissed on it's onPostExecute()).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Now start the AsyncTask.

}
```

Also, please note that when you transit from one activity to other, there will be some delay; which you can not eliminate. I will suggest you to have only once activity.

Comment: This is my code 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.start);
  new Refresh().execute();

Comment: What happens if you remove/comment AsyncTask? If this issue is still there; then it's because of activity switch. Please think to remove temporary activity, it will add a flick effect in UI, which I am sure you will not like.